# Wordpress plugin doesn't load jQuery or CSS

Tags: wordpress

Have used the same code before and it worked so it's not the code thats the problem. I have only changed the class names in the current code but it doesn't load the jQuery or CSS. This is how I call the scripts.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts' );

function scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'style' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', plugins_url('js/jquery.js',__FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Like I said, have used the exact same method before but this time it doesn't work. Don't know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Update: figure out that the plugin dir has space between the words,, removed the space and the plugin works :)

```
function scripts() {
wp_register_style( 'style', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', plugins_url('js/jquery.js',__FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Updated code

V2

```
function scripts() {
if ( ! defined( 'MyPLUGIN_URL' ) )
    define( 'MyPLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

wp_register_style( 'style', MyPLUGIN_URL .'css/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );

wp_register_script( 'jquery', MyPLUGIN_URL .'js/jquery.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: Th first 2 lines of the codes are fixed to register and enque the CSS

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried that but it still didn't load the jQuery and CSS.

Comment: Is your site online? I can see it on my browser?

Comment: I'm using localhost. Have had the same problem before. The scripts didn't load and then a day after it suddently worked.

Comment: you can try the V2 code, I just updated on my answer, I use the same and it works fine everytime. Also ensure that the css and JS are in the same folder :)

Comment: Should i replace the 'MyPLUGIN_URL' with something?

Comment: you can, as long as you change it at all places you see the word 'MyPLUGIN_URL'

Comment: Tried your V2 code and it diden't work either. Now jquery and css doesn't load on my other plugins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94116/discussion-between-lucky-chingi-and-mattesj).

Answer (score 3):

```
function scripts_func()
{
    //----------------------------------------------
    //  Include css file
    //----------------------------------------------
    wp_register_style( 'style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css/style.css', '', '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('style');


    //----------------------------------------------
    //  Include javascript file
    //----------------------------------------------
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js',  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'assets/myjs.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false );

}add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','scripts_func');
```

Comment: Thanks, i made the changes you suggested but it still doesn't load the jQuery or CSS.

Comment: you need not to add jquery by include jquery.js file. A latest jquery file is included with wordpress. You have to just add `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`